# How to move the layoutFragment up when the soft keyboard is shown in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment, android-softkeyboard

I have this page :

[image]

But when open `softWareKeyBoard` I can't see other `EditText`. What can I do?

[image]

NOTICE : I use below code but not worked .And my `class` is `extends Fragment`!

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: Checkout the Edit Answer for your problem

Answer (score 5):

there is two ways to do this  either you can use this in your Manifest activity

it will work for that ,the adjust-pan will flow your surface upward and open the soft keyboard

```html
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

```html
<activity android:name="XXXActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just include `window?.setSoftInputMode( WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)` in onCreate method of your activity containing the Fragment (this will affect all fragments inside activity)

For example:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    window?.setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working Code

For Fragments:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

For Activities:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use can also use `NestedScrollView` as parent view. Set  `fitsSystemWindows = "false"` and set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in manifest file.

Answer (score -2):

I have used like this to show the soft keyboard programatically and this is worked for me to prevent the auto resize of the screen while launching the keyboard.

```
EditText et =  (EditText))findViewById(R.id.edit_text);  
  Timer timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(et.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);

                }
            };
            timer.schedule(task, 200);
```

**In Manifest file use:**

```
<activity android:name="XXXActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
</activity>
```